# Why do I get a 404 on an Azure blob when I ensure it exists first?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am downloading the contents of a blob in Azure, and also checking to make sure the blob exists before downloading. But I still get a 404:

```
    CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blobname.json");
    if (sourceBlob.Exists())
    {
        var blobContents = sourceBlob.DownloadText(); //404 thrown here
    }
```

Shouldn't the `Exists` function return false if the blob doesn't exist?

Comment: How are you connecting to your Storage account? Are you using account name/key or shared access signature?

Comment: I am using a connection string with account name and key (not SAS).

Comment: Please see my last comment below. Can you try that?

Comment: What's the status here? Were you able to solve the issue? I get something similar, so I wonder why I get 404 after I check the blob exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access to the blob in the Azure Storage explorer. 
Public read access for blobs would be the minimum level of access needed

Comment: I am using a connection string with full access to connect to the account. It's the same connection string that was used to create the file. There are millions of these files on there. They are all created the same way. And reading them in this manner (shown above) works fine for the most part. Every soften, we get that 404 error.

Comment: Please trace the request/response using Fiddler. That should give you more information about the error. Please edit your question and include that information.

Comment: @MattSpinks did you ever resolve this? We are seeing the same behavior using SAS strings. Usually it works, but sometimes it gives a 404 on a blob, even though the browser has no problem downloading the file. I have a feeling it is related to some ratelimiting as well.